How to count word frequency with grep (or anything else) with an ignore list of words?
Count frequency of the word person in a file and ignore or do not count if the word is:
personal
personnels
personally
hypersonic

The desired result in sample.txt file is 12 times we have the word `person  in 11 Lines.
A file is called sample.txt with 16 Lines below:
Line 01 count number of times  person  is in file sample.txt
Line 02 Ignore person when it is inside a word like personal, examples, do not count Lines 12 + 
Line 03 but count  person  examples, Line 01 to Line 11 
Line 04 count_ Person or person
Line 05 count_ person, 
Line 06 count_ PERSON; 
Line 07 count_ persons 
Line 08 count_ person’s
Line 09 count_ persons;
Line 10 count_ Persons;
Line 11 count_ “traffic control person” 
Line 12 
Line 13 ignore personal 
Line 14 ignore personnels 
Line 15 ignore personally
Line 16 ignore hypersonic

Command 1: Not a desired result.
grep -IiREnow  --color=always '*person*' sample.txt |wc -l

9
Command 2: Not a desired result.
grep -IiREnowc --color=always '*person*' sample.txt

8
Command 3: Not a desired result.
grep -IiREn    --color=always '*person*' sample.txt

 1:Line 01 count number of times  person  is in file sample.txt
 2:Line 02 Ignore person when it is inside a word like personal, examples, do not count Lines 12 + 
 3:Line 03 but count  person  examples, Line 01 to Line 11 
 4:Line 04 count_ Person or person
 5:Line 05 count_ person, 
 6:Line 06 count_ PERSON; 
 7:Line 07 count_ persons 
 8:Line 08 count_ person’s
 9:Line 09 count_ persons;
10:Line 10 count_ Persons;
11:Line 11 count_ “traffic control person” 
13:Line 13 ignore personal 
14:Line 14 ignore personnels 
15:Line 15 ignore personally
16:Line 16 ignore hypersonic

What is the command that counts person in sample.txt Lines 01 to 11 and ignores person in the 4 words:
personal 
personnels
personally
hypersonic

Using:

OS: Kubuntu 22.04.4 LTS x86_64
grep (GNU grep) 3.7

To display above:
neofetch --stdout |grep 'OS:'

grep --version |head -n1


The question is still unclear as person =/= persons. You are counting persons as a result but it's not the same word... Similarly to personal. What are the exact rules?

Destroy666 typed, The question is still unclear ...
rule1. Increment count +1 when command finds in the file the
6 letters in the word person.
rule2. Case insensitive, means Person or PERSON etc...
Thus rule1+2 says 6 letters in person counts
persons _ person, _ PERSON; _ person’s _
persons; _ person” _ and
rule3. Do not increment for a word that is in the ignore List.
For now, the ignore list has 4 words:
personal
personnels
personally
hypersonic

Said differently, visually command3
on my computer shows person in color red.
grep -IiREn    --color=always '*person*' sample.txt _
Above command3 plus an ignore List would answer the question.

@joseph22 Clarification should be in the question, not in comments. Preferably not as an addendum at the end, but wherever fits best to make the question neat.

grep -iE '\bperson(s|’s)?\b' sample.txt. Add -o and/or pipe to wc -l at will. This is not an answer because you're explicitly asking about implementing exclusions according to the list and the command does not do this.

What about persona? personas? unperson? All of these meet your comment rules in theory. It should be much easier to specify what you want to match than what you don't want to match, especially if your lookup will involve many files with various kinds of data, like usernames. Ignore lists are inefficient and unreliable.

grep -iE '\bperson(s|’s)?\b' sample.txt visually works
because the above command shows 12 person in color red
with original text in white.
Now we count, target is 12 for above file sample.txt _
grep -iE   '\bperson(s|’s)?\b' sample.txt |wc -l counts 11 not 12.
grep -iEc  '\bperson(s|’s)?\b' sample.txt counts 11 not 12.
grep -iEo  '\bperson(s|’s)?\b' sample.txt shows 12.
grep -iEoc '\bperson(s|’s)?\b' sample.txt counts 11 not 12.
grep -iEo  '\bperson(s|’s)?\b' sample.txt |wc -l counts 12.

grep -iEo  '\bperson(s|’s)?\b' sample.txt |wc -l
counts 12 = answers the Question.  See command posted by Kamil Maciorowski.

grep -iEo  '\bperson(s|’s)?\b' sample.txt |wc -l
above command is the accecpted answer and above command has limits,
as noted by Destroy666,
because command does not capture a different question
with file containing
persona or personas or unperson or tradesperson

I am not sure the solution matches what you are wanting to do, but it would appear to do what you ask - although I am sure someone with decent regex skills could come up with something better -
cat test.file | tr " " "\n" | grep -i "person" | egrep -iv "personal|personnels|personally|hypersonic" | wc -l

The tr part tokenizes the input into 1 line per word to make it easier to grep. The first grep is a case insensitive search for person, the second handles the words you want to exclude, which is then counted.
Maybe a more suitable generic solution which does not rely on your wordlists would be:
tr " " "\n" < test.file | egrep -ic "^(person|persons)\b"


cat sample.txt | tr " " "\n" | grep -i "person" | egrep -iv "personal|personnels|personally|hypersonic" | wc -l counts 12, answers the Question.

tr " " "\n" < sample.txt | egrep -ic "^(person|persons)\b" counts 12, answers the Question.
